# Build breaks image link

Tags: build, polymer

I need to get my image link to work after building my app. How do I make `polymer build` translate an image path from the `src` directory to `build/bundled/src`?

My file structure began looking something like this:

```
my-app/
  index.html
  images/
    my-image.png
  src/
    my-element.html
```

I link to an image file in `my-element` as follows:

my-app/src/my-element.html

```
<img src="../images/my-image.png">
```

The image looks great.

To build my app, I run the following command:

```
polymer build
```

To view what I just built, I run:

```
polymer serve build/bundled
```

Now the image link is broken. So I check the source code in the `build/bundled` directory and notice the `<img src` path reference did not change nor was any new `images/` subdirectory created in the `build/bundled/` subdirectory. Instead, I see the following:

my-app/build/bundled/src/my-element.html

```
<img src="../images/my-image.png">
```

To make that work, the file structure should have a new `images/` subdirectory and look as follows:

```
my-app/
  index.html
  images/
    my-image.png
  src/
    my-element.html
  build/
    bundled/
      index.html
      src/
        my-element.html
      images/
        my-image.png
```

But, instead, it does not. And looks like this:

```
my-app/
  index.html
  images/
    my-image.png
  src/
    my-element.html
  build/
    bundled/
      index.html
      src/
        my-element.html
```

And, therefore, the `<img src` link breaks.

How can I fix this in my `polymer build` process? Do I need to add something, perhaps, to my `polymer.json`, `manifest.json`, `package.json`, `gulpfile.js` or similar files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add an `includeDependencies` array to your `polymer.json` file:

```
{
  "includeDependencies": [
    "images/**/*"
  ]
}
```